# Visibility hidden removes background color in a table

Tags: html, css

I am building an app and I have a table dynamically created.

The table rows are created as follows

```
<tr style="background-color: #71aa9a;">
  <td></td>
  .
  . 
  .
  <td></td>
<tr/>
```

And some of the *td's* are hidden during creation .

The problem that arises is that when a *td* is invisible (*visibility:hidden*) the background color of *tr* is disappeared and is white instead.

Can someone explain me why and how can i solve it ?

I dont want to use display:none; due to the need of specific td's in a row.

Comment: `opacity: 0;` work as an alternative but I don't have the *why*

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/7cs1zhLd/1/ I get the issue in Firefox but not Chrome. It really feels like background color applied to tr is in fact applied directly to td, but finding some reference about this would be neat.

Comment: In each table cell wrap content in a div and apply css on it as a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry I don't have a more definitive explanation about the issue, but the fact is that background properties on `<tr>` elements are finicky. If I was you I'd just wrap cell content in a `<div>` and do `visibility: hidden` on that instead.

```
<tr>
  <td><div style="visibility: hidden">You dont see me!</div></td>
  <td>etc.</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'd use trick using mainly `font-size: 0`, which will make content invisible, unselectable. Styles for all inner elements (`>*`) are here to overwrite default values.

#### Snippet

```css
tr {
  background: red;
}

.hidden,
.hidden>* {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td class="hidden"><button onclick="">Smith</button></td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Making the cell's content transparent does not prevent the content from being selected and copy-pasted, nor does it prevent links or buttons from being clicked.

Comment: Plus I have buttons in it that can be clicked. But thank you for the response

Comment: @lampyridae : that's right, but if you have any other solution w/o JS I'm all ears.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer. New trick should do the job in all cases.

Comment: Using `font-size: 0; background-color: black;` works for me. It retains my background color. Using `visibility: hidden` removes background color.